# Local notification in Cordova application

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, cordova-plugins

I'm developing an APP with Cordova and ExpressJS for Android and IOS.

I am developing the notification module.

I'm using Google GCM to send the notification to the APP and the phonegap-plugin-push plugin to receive the notification in the APP.

The APP is receiving the notification, but I need to notify the operating system.

PROBLEM: I need to know how to send a local notification to the operating system or some plugin that works correctly. It needs to work with the APP open and closed.

The cordova-plugin-local-notification plugin works, however it does not display icons with APP closed and does not work on some devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more : https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications
Basics
The plugin creates the object cordova.plugins.notification.local and is accessible after deviceready has been fired.

cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    title: 'My first notification',
    text: 'Thats pretty easy...',
    foreground: true
});

Installation
The plugin can be installed via Cordova-CLI and is publicly available on NPM.

Execute from the projects root folder:

$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification
Or install a specific version:

$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification@VERSION
Or install the latest head version:

$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git
Or install from local source:

$ cordova plugin add  --nofetch --nosave --link